# SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: is operator cannot find class with name:

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to check camel choice condition in `when` with calling the method but which is failing and throws exception.Please help me to check the method return value with constant value.

**Exception:**

> SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: is operator cannot find class with name:
>   VS at location 22 ${body.recType} is 'VS'

**Route:**

```
from("direct:processAccounts").process(filterProcessor). 
 split(simple("${body}")).choice().when().
 simple("${body.recType} is 'VS'").
 process((exchange) -> {log.info("VS:");}).otherwise().to("stream:out");
```

Java Class:

```
public class Records{

    private String recType;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` operator is like `instanceof` in Java. If you want to do an equals comparison on the string value, then use

```
simple("${body.recType} == 'VS'").
```

See the simple documentation: http://camel.apache.org/simple